# Ember: this.transitionTo works only once

Tags: ember.js

I got a "Settings"-Controller for my route "/settings".

But this specific route does not exist. There are only following routes:

- /settings/account
- /settings/system

Now, i want to redirect all "/settings" requests to "/settings/account".
This works fine, ... but just once.

If i click on a button with the target "/settings" i get redirected to "/settings/account". But if i click a second time on that same button, there is no redirect and it gets me on "/settings".

Here is my code:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   redirect() {
     this.transitionTo('settings.account');         
   }
});
```

Why does this works just once?

Answer (score 1):

Redirect is kinda special. You can read more about how exactly it works [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_redirect).
It looks like you don't want to fire model hooks here at all so you should redirect it like this.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel() {
    this.transitionTo('settings.account');
  },
});
```